# RegOpenKeyEx redundant parameter?

Tags: windows, api

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> ulOptions
>
> ```
> This parameter is reserved and must be zero.
> ```

What was the reason behind placing this formal parameter, whereas it always must be the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Microsoft docs don't say anything but the [wine code](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/advapi32/registry.c#L438) does: `RegKeyOpenEx()` accepts the `REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK` value to `options`, which in the case of registry keys that are links, opens the link itself rather than following the link and opening the target.

However since it's not in the official docs, I don't recommend using it.  Since Micrsoft don't mention it, they don't officially support it, and are free (within practical limits) to stop that working in a windows update or whatever.

Microsoft are free to add whatever parameters they like to their functions simply to have a parameter to make use of later on.  It can save them having to create new functions (although they don't seem to have done too well in that regard anyway).

Answer (score 2):

That parameter most likely meant something in an earlier version of the OS, possibly even pre-release internal versions. But the feature it controlled has been removed, or was never publicly released.

Once binaries have been built that used that parameter, MS would not have wanted to change the signature of the function. Doing so would have broken those pre-existing binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft was just planning ahead, allowing for options to be passed in the future without breaking the API.

Always setting it to zero now prevents applications from breaking, in case they change how the API handles that parameter in the future. The parameter is most likely ignored for now, but say you start passing 42 to it, and in the next version of windows, they decide to actually change behavior based on that parameter. Now your application behaves differently.

Moral of the story: adhere to what the documentation says.

Comment: I'm not sure that's very likely. I can't think of any time that ever happened, where a reserved parameter was re-purposed. Do you know of such an example from history?

Comment: Its done all the time with specific bits in a bitfield. Since the parameter is named `ulOptions` one can infer that this is just the special case of that, where all bits are currently reserved.

Comment: Bitfields is different. I'm saying that I've not known a full parameter be re-purposed. And if it has happened, it hasn't happened often. And if what you are saying is true, why do so many API functions not have reserved parameters?

Comment: We are arguing over something that cannot easily be proven either way. However, considering this is a registry function (notoriously complicated) and this is the Ex (more parameters, functionality, etc) maybe they just thought it'd be a good idea here.

Comment: I agree that we are both speculating. The reason I don't think MS put in spare parameters intentionally is that they could never use them anyway. Because there would be some apps that passed the wrong thing to the dummy parameter and would therefore break on new Windows.

Comment: The lpReserved in DllMain got repurposed in Windows NT 3.5.

Comment: @RaymondChen Very nice. An example from someone on the inside. Of course DllMain is a little different since the call is made from OS to client, rather than client to OS and that changes the back-compat equation. Am I right in thinking that there would be a general presumption against repurposing for back-compat reasons?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Regarding the dummy parameter arguments, that's exactly why I suspect the documentation states that a zero must be passed.